# Create lat and lon columns from string stored as XML

Tags: xml, t-sql, xquery

I have stored data in following format in `Nvarchar` data type field

```
<geoPos lat="24.569408d" lon="54.647884d"/>
```

I want to get Lat and Lon values from above string as 2 columns.

Comment: You don't need our permission, just go ahead and do it. If you have a problem, then post a _question_. Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on writing a question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 2):

Cast to `XML` and use the [`Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type) method.

This should get you started:

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Col varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('<geoPos lat="24.569408d" lon="54.647884d"/>'),
('<geoPos lat="20.573082d" lon="57.478468d"/>')
```

The query:

```
SELECT  Col, 
        CAST(Col As XML).value('(geoPos/@lat)[1]', 'varchar(10)') As Lat,
        CAST(Col As XML).value('(geoPos/@lon)[1]', 'varchar(10)') As lon
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
Col                                             Lat         lon
<geoPos lat="24.569408d" lon="54.647884d"/>     24.569408d  54.647884d
<geoPos lat="20.573082d" lon="57.478468d"/>     20.573082d  57.478468d
```

Please note I've used `varchar(10)` since that's the number of characters in the values you use. If you have longer values you will need a longer varchar.

Also, If you want to store the latitude and longitude in the database, SQL Server (since 2008) supports [spatial geography](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/spatial-types-geography) data types. I personally have no experience with this data type, so I will not attempt to demonstrate how to work with it.

Comment: Thanks Zohar Solved

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Comment: @Ali, If this answer helped you to solve your issue, it would be kind to tick the acceptance check below the answer's vote counter. When you've passed the 15 rep-points-border yourself, you are - additionally asked to vote on contributions.

Comment: Hi, Here is the full XML string